# Display 2nd element 1st (CSS)

Tags: html, css

My code is the following:

```
<div class="item">
<div class="img">Hello this is img</div>
<div class="text">Hello this is text</div>
</div>
```

I want it to display it as

> Hello this is the text
>   Hello is the img

I want this achieve without reordering code. Preferably with css. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot do that reliably with CSS, but you can do it with a couple lines of Javascript.

Comment: I did it with CSS, by using position

Answer (score 3):

```
   .item .text{float:left;display:inline;}
   .item .img{display:inline}
```

try with css3 `transform` for vertical alignment

```
     .item .text{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%);}
      .item .img{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%);}
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6B7qt/4/

Comment: The [formatting of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f92c7d1a-4d0e-4721-8c61-369f84a79446/view-source) was wrong. While this answer is good for inline elements, it does not work in this case.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 i HAVE UPDATED THE answer for vertical alignment

Comment: How do you know the height of `.text` without JS?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 . you dont have to. see UPDATED ANS with the fiddle link

Comment: Well, I don't know why you keep editing your answer, but this time it works only if `.text` has the same height as `.img`: http://jsfiddle.net/e3j4b/

Comment: @Pumbaa80 you might want to clearify your requirements in the question then. and even in your fiddle, text is coming before the image.

Answer (score 1):

The sophisticated way to do this is to use [CSS flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#order-property).

```
.item { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.text { order: -1; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKmwV/1/

However, IE [does not support this](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) at the moment, so you'll have to use some hacks. Not sure if a general solution is possible without JS.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest way, but you could always use absolute positioning:

```
.item {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
}

.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Just for the record, I'd look at using some simple Javascript, but this is a dirty hack :)

Comment: How do you know the height of `.text` without JS?

Comment: In your example, font-size. It's not clean, like I said :)

Comment: The margin example above, although again not brilliant, should be preferred over mine

Answer (score 0):

The CSS2.1 way ([example](http://jsbin.com/ufuguc/1/edit)):

```
.item { display: table; }
.img { display: table-footer-group; }
```

Doesn't work only in IE7-. However, some CSS properties like margins, borders etc. won't apply to the element with `display: table-*-group`, so an extra wrapper may be needed.